# Can I use 0.5 HP slow speed monoblock for high pressure car cleaning

Tags: water, water-pressure, pump, water-tank

I have [0.5 HP self priming slow speed monoblock pump](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/kumar-slow-speed-monobloc-pumps-23852248633.html) which gets the water to overhead water tank.

I'm thinking to have a lever to divert the water from pump to [high pressure water gun with hose](https://www.amazon.in/Trendegic-Plastic-Trigger-Pressure-Washing/dp/B08VWZL7D3/ref=sr_1_20?crid=2Z06NFBIK1XC0&keywords=High%20Pressure%20Water%20Spray%20Gun%20for%20Car%2FBike%2FPlants%7CMulti%20Functional%20Water%20Spray%20Nozzle%20for%20Gardening%7CSpray%20Gun%20with%20Handle%7CWater%20Spray%20Gun%20for%20Car%20Wash%20-%20Gardening%20Washing&qid=1684095536&s=automotive&sprefix=high%20pressure%20water%20spray%20gun%20for%20car%2Fbike%2Fplants%20multi%20functional%20water%20spray%20nozzle%20for%20gardening%20spray%20gun%20with%20handle%20water%20spray%20gun%20for%20car%20wash%20-%20gardening%20washing%2Cautomotive%2C227&sr=1-20).

Is it a bad idea to use the same pump for both pumping to overhead tank and cleaning floor/car etc..

Will the motor get ruined sooner ?

Or is there any recommendation ?

Update:

I could use water tap but I don't there would be a good pressure and I have to run the hose for longer distance. Hence I'm trying to reuse the same water pump.

Buying a high speed water washing costs huge money so I'm preferring not to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, the pump has a maximum head of 49M which is about 65 PSIG. There is no information on the nozzle or what the definition of high pressure is. To me high pressure for washing is several hundred PSIG minimum.

You have some control over the pressure by restricting the flow. Using a standard garden hose nozzle should do the trick, just do not leave it in the off position. The lower the flow the higher the pressure until head pressure (about 65 PSIG) is reached.

Comment: Thanks. I need something good enough to clean the dust particles off the car that's all :) I'm wondering .. whether 0.5 hp would give pressure that's good enough and  attaching a new hose and water gun.. would it affect the pump ?